# Formatting date with JavaScript in a customer fronting e-commerce application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, formatdatetime

We have a situation where in we need to format a json response attribute which contains a date string (say "2017-01-29"). To format the date we are currently using jquery UI function like:

```
dayVar = $.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', new Date("2017-01-29"));
```

But if we print dayVar, it is displayed as Jan 28, 17 as against the expected Jan 29, 17.
What is the best solution to fix this so that it can fit into any time zone?

It is single page application built with Marionette framework.

Comment: which version of jQuery ui and jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery -  v1.8.3 and jQuery UI - v1.11.4

Comment: could you check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv5n2yde/)

Comment: It says Jan 28, 2017 it should be Jan 29, 2017

Comment: Please take care to correctly spell 'JavaScript', avoiding search collision with Java.

Comment: you should use moment js for that kind of manipulations [check this link](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When instantiating your new Date object, you are leaving the Time up to interpretation.  By default most environments will interpret this to 00:00:00 ... however, as this is javascript you are at the mercy of the user's local machine to interpret this value.

I would append the 00:00:00 in the string to the Date() function. to enforce the expected outcome, or even attempt to play with the time to see what kind of outputs it creates (Maybe set it for 1AM or 22:00:00) this should provide a more in depth understanding of what is causing the issue, and hopefully the solution.

Comment: Will this work?

var dateVar = new Date("2017-01-29");
dateVar = $.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', new Date(dateVar.getTime() + (60000 * dateVar.getTimezoneOffset())));

Comment: It may, I'm not able to reproduce the issue so I am unable to provide testing.  I would start by updating your code to a test run of var dateVar = new Date("2017-01-29 00:00:00");  

See if that provides any change in behavior, then you can test your code above to see what impact it has!

Comment: Thank you for marking the answer correct!  I'm glad this either solved your issue or led you down the correct path to resolution! Many Thanks and goodluck on your project!